# VBA Finding Last Row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy down a formula down to the last row. I've got code for doing so but it won't work.

My code to find the last row is:

```
lRow = ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The rest of my code is as follows:

```
Sub Inventory()
Dim lRow As Integer

lRow = ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Inventory Macro
Range("G2").Select
' Selects cell G2
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-RC[-2]"
' Calculates Inventory for the first month by subtracting Production Units from Demand
Range("G3").Select
' Selects cell G3
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-RC[-2]+R[-1]C"
' Calculates Inventory for the rest of the months by subtracting Production Units from Demand plus the previous month's Inventory
Range("G3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G3:G" & lRow)
Range("G3:G" & lRow).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably stems from the column in which you determine the last row. Here is another version of your code that avoids selecting anything.

```
Sub Inventory2()
    'Inventory Macro
    ' Calculates Inventory for the rest of the months by subtracting
    ' Production Units from Demand plus the previous month's Inventory

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet            ' better: name the sheet: Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Ws
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   ' this can't be column G
        .Cells(2, "G").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-RC[-2]"
        .Range(.Cells(3, "G"), .Cells(lRow, "G")).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-RC[-2]+R[-1]C"
    End With
End Sub
```